# Jquery hover menu with orphaned sub-menu options

Tags: jquery, menu, hover

I have a simply drop-down menu system, when the user hovers over an option in the drop-down a sub-menu appears with more clickable options.

The problem I have is that if someone wants to make a selection from menu option "comp 4" the sum-menu disappears too quickly and so the option is orphaned and can't ever been selected. I have strippe dback all options to for the demonstration purposes but you can see the issue here:

http://jsfiddle.net/dt8kz/

I think a delay needs to be applied at line 23 (jesfiddle):

```
,function(){
         $('ul.fixture-list').delay(100).slideUp(50);        
});
```

I tried this but it doesn't work as expected.

Thanks,

Alan.

Answer (score 0):

I used to do these tricks before.

Just the Delay won't work, what you have to accomplish is one timer varialble and also a status saying if it is being hovered on.

Its a bit of a dirty way, but here is the working example, i remove some invalid html and put in some more functions.

http://jsfiddle.net/L48VL/1/

```
var hideTimer;
var Hovering = false;
    function HideFixture()
    {
        if(!Hovering)
        {
            $('#nav li.matches > ul').stop().slideUp(50);
            $('ul.fixture-list').slideUp(50);  
        }

    }
function ShowSub()
{
    clearTimeout(hideTimer); 
     $('.fixture-list').show();
}
```

Then On Hover, we do like this

```
$('#nav li').hover(
    function () {
        //show its submenu
         Hovering = true; 
        clearTimeout(hideTimer);
         $('#nav li.matches > ul.first').stop().slideDown(100);

    }, 
    function () {
        //hide its submenu
            Hovering = false; 
            hideTimer = setTimeout(HideFixture,300);   
        //$('ul.fixture-list').removeAttr('style');         

    }
);
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Awesome thank you, I have not tried your solution yet but I will do when I get a chance. I appreciate your help!